# How to restrict the length of INTEGER when creating a table in ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle

all

When creating a table in Oracle sql*plus, I want to restrict that the length of an INTEGER column can **only be 8**.

eg: the RegNumber is an INTEGER, and it must be a 8 digit number.

How can I do this when I creating a table?

Comment: do you want 00000001 to be stored as 00000001 or 1, e.g. is this 8 digit number a fixed length regardless?

Comment: For completeness, is -12345678 an acceptable eight digit number in your case?

Comment: yes, I want 000000001 to be stored as 00000001, NOT 1, cause I want an 8 digit number, exactly 8!

Comment: If you insist on storing 1 as 00000001, you need to format it as a string before inserting and store it in a Varchar(8) field since at that point it is an 8 character string. If you store it as a number, just use a number formatting function after extracting the data from the database to display it how you like.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The INTEGER datatype is just a subtype of NUMBER. You can define the column as NUMBER(8,0) to get you an integer column that is <= 8 digits.

If you are trying to ensure that the column is 8 digits and ONLY 8 digits, you'll need to add a check constraint on the column:

```
CREATE TABLE RegTable
(RegNumber NUMBER(8,0),
CONSTRAINT CheckRegNumber  CHECK (RegNumber > 9999999)
);
```

Comment: +1, But, why use a NUMBER type and not an INT?   You can have > 9999999 AND < 100000000...

Comment: INT/INTEGER is just a subtype of NUMBER in Oracle that is defined as NUMBER(38,0). Storage/performance is the same since oracle stores numbers in variable-length fields on the back end. It *might* be a slight speed improvement to only have one check constraint instead of two, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: @Dems, your method is good, but I can only insert values from 10000000 to 99999999 (not include 00000000 - 09999999), they are all 8 digit numbers, but is there any possible method that regard 00000001 also a valid 8 digit number?

Comment: @Truman'sworld - Just check that the number is `>= 0 and <= 99999999` and then use STUFF or PAD when converting the numeric value to a string value.  (because 1 and 00000001 are the same *number*)

Comment: I agree with @Dems. Upon retreival, just use a number formatting function in whatever client tool you're using to display 1 as 00000001.

Comment: @Dems could you please show me how to change the format using STUFF or PAD?

Comment: @Truman'sworld - Actually `to_char(col1, '00000000')` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Just specify a length of 8 and a precision of 0.  Like this

```
SQL> create table t8 (col1 number(8,0))
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> insert into t8 values (12345678)
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t8 values (123456789)
  2  /
insert into t8 values (123456789)
                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column


SQL>
```

To enforce an exact length (all numbers must be eight digits long) you'll need to use a CHECK constraint:

```
SQL> alter table t8 
  2  add constraint t8_ck check (length(col1) = 8)
  3  /

Table altered.

SQL> insert into t8 values (1234567)
  2  /
insert into t8 values (1234567)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (APC.T8_CK) violated


SQL>
```

Comment: +0 : In oracle, LENGTH() takes a string.  This means that you're using a fixed point type to represent an INT, then implicitly casting it to a string to check it's length.  It work, but, *yikes* ;)

Comment: @Dems - not sure why you go "yikes".  I've run some wall-clock tests inserting ten thousand rows at a time and the check constraint as I specified it makes *no appreciable difference* to the elapsed time.

Comment: Really?  That's not what I expected.  As, however, you've tested it and, as you say, there is no *appreciable* difference, I'd say it's a decent answer then... +1

Comment: @Dems - of course clock timings are not completely reliable.  FWIW, on my 11g VM the inserts ranged from 0.05s to 0.20s without the check, and 0.06s to 0.20s with it.  In other words, the impact on ambient system conditions (checkpoint etc) is greater than any effect of the implicit conversion.  But YMMV.

Comment: @ACP , if I insert 00000001 into this table, the length of this NUMBER is regard as 8 or 1 ?

Comment: @Truman'sworld - `check(length(to_char(col1, '00000000')) = 8)`?  (While a *numeric* `1 == 00000001`, you're talking about a formatted string, not a number)